# Angular material put image on selected value of <mat-select>

Tags: html, angular, css, angular-material

I am using angular material in an angular 2 project.
I want to put a static image (html element) in the selected value of mat-select. 
But i didn't find a solution. 
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By simply adding `<img>` tag inside `<mat-option>`. For the selected option use `ngClass` to set the image as background. You must use one class by option:

**HTML**

```
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected" [ngClass]="selected">
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1
      <img with="10" height="10" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg">

    </mat-option>      
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2
      <img with="10" height="10" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/learning-area/master/html/multimedia-and-embedding/images-in-html/dinosaur_small.jpg">

    </mat-option>

    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```

**CSS:**

```
.option1{
  background:  url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg")  center / contain no-repeat;
  white-space: nowrap

}


.option2{
  background:  url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mdn/learning-area/master/html/multimedia-and-embedding/images-in-html/dinosaur_small.jpg")  center / contain no-repeat;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:inline
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydugqt?file=src/app/select-overview-example.ts)**

Comment: Iputed a mat-select and images inside it is for internationalisation it works but when i select a flag(exp:frensh) i did not see the flag selected appeared

Comment: Check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kc4dir. I was unable to add image so added an emoji. You can replace content with background or background-image with url

Comment: in this exemple they put the same image on css but i have different images :/

Answer (score 40):

[image]

when it comes to this or similar situation, I did it that:

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-select [(value)]="selectedLanguage">
       <mat-select-trigger>
         <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ selectedLanguage | lowercase}}"> </span>
       </mat-select-trigger>
       <mat-option *ngFor="let lang of Languages" [value]="lang">
         <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-{{ lang | lowercase}}"></span>
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

of course, inside tags `<mat-select-trigger>` and ` can be any tags as well img, and they work !!

Comment: It seems like the default trigger just does 'toString()' on everything inside the `mat-option` and concatenates it together. Unfortunately there's no easy way for the framework to use your `mat-option` HTML for the default trigger because it is just HTML that could have been generated in all kinds of ways.

Comment: How to set the same value while getting the array of data from database?

Comment: You don't need a  two-way data binding in the `mat-select`. Use a hashtag `#selectedLanguage"` instead, like `<mat-select #selectedLanguage>` and go check with `selectedLanguage.value` if you're using a formGroup ;)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use Mat Select Trigger check: https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelectTrigger

```
<mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>....</mat-label>
      <mat-select [formControl]="fromControl">
        <mat-select-trigger>
          <img src="assets/images/currencies/{{fromControl.value}}.svg">
          <span>{{fromControl.value}}</span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option>
          <img src="imageSrc">
          <span>...</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting a `<span>` within the `<mat-select-trigger>` and/or `<mat-option>` elements, then binding html to it after the fashion precribed by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58741354/507721).

```html
<mat-select>
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <span [innerHTML]="myHtmlWithImageTag"></span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
    <span [innerHTML]="myHtmlWithImageTag"></span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: what is - i use multiple?

Comment: @KumaresanSd can you clarify your question? I'm not sure how to parse your words.

Comment: sorry typo mistake, what if, i use multipl option in mat-select. can we able to add multiple images?

Comment: @KumaresanSd if I understand, you're suggesting that you might have multiple `<mat-option>` elements. Do you mean with the `ngFor` or explicitly hardcoding the elements? In either case, your innerHTML may interpolate properties of your `item`, so you might have your image urls stored on the `item` object.