# use of [innerHTML] inside <mat-select><mat-option>

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material

I try to use `[innerHTML]` inside `<mat-option>` of `<mat-select>` which works fine for the drop-down list, but not for the selected value.

Versions:

- Browser Google Chrome 68.0.3440.106 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Angular 6.1.6
- Angular material 6.4.6
- bootstrap 4.1.3
- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap 3.2.0

In my example the used code is

```
<mat-form-field class="col-11">
  <mat-select 
    [(ngModel)]="node.nodeType" 
    (change)="nodeTypeChanged()" 
    placeholder="{{'node.node_type' | translate}}"
    [compareWith]="compareObjects">
    <mat-option 
      *ngFor="let item of nodeTypes" 
      [value]="item">
      <span [innerHTML]="item.iconVisual.iconCodeHtml"></span>
      <span> {{item.label}}</span>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The attached screen captures with combo box unselected where the task icon is not rendered and the selected combo box where the icons are correctly rendered, shows the problem.

Selected combo box: icon not rendered

[image]

Unselected combo box: all icons rendered

[image]

Simplified stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjs5sn?embed=1&file=src/app/hello.component.ts).

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please create a quick stackblitz project for this?

Comment: please from browser , indicate that unloaded material and paste the code along with it's css so i can help you

Comment: stackblitz added to question

Comment: just tell me what you see when you open developer tool f12 and point the selector on it ... do you see any errors in path or something

Comment: check my new answer and let me know if u still facing issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is to use `<mat-select-trigger>` element:

like:

```
 <mat-select-trigger>
            <span [innerHTML]="nodeType.iconHtml"></span>
              <span> {{ nodeType.label }}</span>
        </mat-select-trigger>
```

This is how it will look the full example: **[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-elon3g-ukeeav)**

```
template: `
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-select [(ngModel)]="nodeType" placeholder="NodeType">
      <mat-select-trigger>
        <span [innerHTML]="nodeType.iconHtml"></span>
          <span> {{ nodeType.label }}</span>
    </mat-select-trigger>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of nodeTypes" [value]="item">
          <span [innerHTML]="item.iconHtml"></span>
          <span> {{ item.label }}</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      h1 {
        font-family: Lato;
      }
    `
  ]
})
```

Comment: what is - i use multiple?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone (future me included) trying this with form control and not ngModel, you can do it like so:

```html
<mat-select #mSelect formControlName="controlName">
  <mat-select-trigger>
    <span [innerHTML]="htmlArray[mSelect.value]"></span>
  </mat-select-trigger>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let html of htmlArray; let idx = index"
              [value]="idx">
     <span [innerHTML]="html"></span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! But there's is a trap for young players:
`this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(var)`. You should use this too I think (or `var escArr = htmlArray.map(h => this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(h))`).

Comment: In the latest Angular I don't think that's an issue as it's sanitising HTML (stripping script elements etc.) automatically

Answer (score 0):

I was digging into the issue and I found out its a bug within unicode conversion  while exporting the hello component.

To fix this issue replace your code with one below

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
svg,
img,
png,
png2x,
png3x,
aliases,
icons,
iconsByUnicodeHex
} from 'font-awesome-assets';

@Component({
selector: 'hello',
template: `
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="nodeType" placeholder="NodeType">
<mat-option *ngFor="let item of nodeTypes" [value]="item">
<span [innerHTML]="item.iconHtml"></span>
<span> {{item.label}}</span>
</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>`,
styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`] 
})

export class HelloComponent  {
@Input() name: string;
nodeType ;
nodeTypes = [ 
{
  label: 'Task',
  iconHtml: '<i class="fa">&#xf0e7;</i>'
}, 
{
  label: 'Project',
  iconHtml: svg('briefcase', rgba(0,0,0,0.5))
}
]

ngOnInit() {
this.nodeType = this.nodeTypes[1];
}
}
```

It should ask you to install the missing package of font-awesome library when your replace your code

Install it and it should work ... let me know if you had any issue

good luck