# Display image in mat-select coming from mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

So, i have a piece of html that includes a mat-form-field who have a mat-select and an mat-option. Those mat-options are generated from the server and they have an image that i need to display in the mat-select when an option is selected(every option has his own image)

```
<mat-select>
    <ng-container
            *ngFor="let option of options">
            <mat-option>
                <!-- Image -->
                    <img
                        height="24px"
                        [src]="option[optionLabelImgKey]"/>
                !-- Label -->
                {{option[optionLabelKey] | translate}}
            </mat-option>
     </ng-container>
</mat-select>
```

I want to display the optionLabel and the image in the mat-select every time a new option is selected.

I've read about mat-select-trigger but nothing works for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular material put image on selected value of <mat-select>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365847/angular-material-put-image-on-selected-value-of-mat-select)

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this:

```
<img height="24px" src="option[optionLabelImgKey]"/>
```

Maybe your problem is that the img is not displayed due to it cannot acces to the file (bad route).

By the way I created a fork at stackblitz with a working example of a list of images inside the `mat-select` you can have a look at:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9txen8